# Valid Parenthese in a string (Haskell implementation)

Tags: haskell

the problem is to check whether parentheses in a string is properly closed or not. For Haskell implementation, so far I have following. It looks quite awkward. I am looking for a more "Haskell-style" or more elegant implementation.

```
import Data.List

isValidParentheses :: String -> Bool
isValidParentheses = isValidHelper . (filter isParenthese)

getIndex :: (Eq a) => a -> [a] -> Int
getIndex c xs =  getOut (elemIndex c xs)
  where getOut (Just x) = x
        getOut Nothing = -1

isLeftParenthese :: Char -> Bool
isLeftParenthese c = (getIndex c "{[(") /= -1

isRightParenthese :: Char -> Bool
isRightParenthese c = (getIndex c "}])") /= -1

isParenthese :: Char -> Bool
isParenthese c = isLeftParenthese c || isRightParenthese c


isValidHelper :: String -> Bool
isValidHelper xs = helper xs []
  where helper (x:xs) []     | isRightParenthese x = False
                             | otherwise = helper xs [x]
        helper [] st = null st
        helper (x:xs) (s:ss) | isLeftParenthese x = helper xs (x:s:ss)
                              | ((getIndex x "}])") /= (getIndex s "{[(")) = False
                              | otherwise = helper xs ss
```

Thanks

Comment: `getIndex c xs /= -1` can be replaced by `elem c xs`. After this, `getIndex` should be removed: you can compare the `Maybe Int` result of `elemIndex` directly, if you want. Transforming `Nothing` into `-1` is very un-Haskellish: at best it is useless (as in this case), at worst it prods the programmer to forget about the "not found" case. Finally, your code does not handle other chars e.g. `a(b[c]d)e` is not valid -- this is intended, right?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Checking if a string consists of balanced parenthesis](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7209260/checking-if-a-string-consists-of-balanced-parenthesis)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Loop through the string
- Store opening parentheses in stack
- Pop matching parentheses out of the stack
- Check if stack is empty at the end

  ```
  isValid = loop []
    where
      match '(' ')' = True
      match '{' '}' = True
      match '[' ']' = True
      match  _   _  = False

      loop st [] = null st
      loop st (x:xs)
        | x `elem` "([{" = loop (x:st) xs
        | x `elem` ")]}" = case st of
          open : st' | match open x -> loop st' xs
          _ -> False -- unmatched close
        | otherwise = loop st xs
  ```